# How to test a file exists from a Kubernetes probe?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

I have a sidecar container in a MySQL Pod which will use the MySQL socket file in order to access the database.

I would like to be sure MySQL has successfully started and therefore have created the socket file before than this sidecar container starts.

I tried to add a `readiness` probe with an `exec.command` being `test -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` but it fails with:

```
Readiness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "test -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock": stat test -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock: no such file or directory: unknown
```

When I open a terminal session in the sidecar container, I can `ls` the socket file and it's there.

So it looks like my `test -S <path>` command doesn't work as expected in the context of the probe.

How can I write my probe so that as soon as the socket file is available my sidecar container starts?

Comment: have tried adding some `initialDelaySeconds` ? just incase the file isn't created in the startup and shows up maybe a few seconds late?

Comment: Yes I did add one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
...
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - test -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```